# Django 'ModelForm' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a ModelForm and I'm trying to display it with some of the fields disabled. In this case, `process_id`.
The important part of my Model looks like this:

#### models.py

```
class Process(models.Model):
    related_processes = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    process_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    normal_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # a lot of fields here...
```

So basically I have a Process that can have zero or more related processes.
This is what I have on forms.py:

#### forms.py

```
class ProcessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = '__all__'


class EditProcessForm(ProcessForm):
    readonly_fields = ('process_id', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProcessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in (field for name, field in self.fields.items() if name in self.readonly_fields):
            field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'true'
            field.required = False

    def clean(self):
        for f in self.readonly_fields:
            self.cleaned_data.pop(f, None)
        return super(EditProcessForm, self).clean()


class NewVersionProcessForm(EditProcessForm):
    readonly_fields = ('process_id', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewVersionProcessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in (field for name, field in self.fields.items() if name in self.readonly_fields):
            # field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'true'
            # Remember this line ^
            field.required = False
```

The first time the client is filling the form, I want all fields to be editable, so I use ProcessForm. But when the client is editing the Process, I want some fields to be read-only. I found this nice solution here on stackoverflow (unfortunately I couldn't find it again) and it works perfectly when I'm editing a process.
The difference between EditProcessForm and NewVersionProcessForm is their Views and the commented line on `__init__`.

#### views.py

```
class ProcessFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'my_app/fill_form.html'
    form_class = ProcessForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect('my_app:show_process_page', form.cleaned_data.get('process_id'))


class EditProcessView(UpdateView):
    model = Process
    form_class = EditProcessForm
    template_name = 'my_app/edit_form.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'process_id'

    def post(self, request, process_id):
        # This is a little hack I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262262/3773461
        # to edit an immutable QueryDict.
        mutable = request.POST._mutable
        request.POST._mutable = True
        request.POST['process_id'] = process_id
        request.POST._mutable = mutable
        return super().post(request)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect('my_app:show_process_page', self.kwargs['process_id'])

class NewVersionProcessView(EditProcessView):
    template_name = 'my_app/new_version_form.html'
    form_class = NewVersionProcessForm

    def get(self, request, process_id):
        try:
            Process.objects.get(process_id=process_id)
            return redirect('my_app:process_already_exists_page')
        except Process.DoesNotExist:
            self.object = Process(process_id=process_id)
            last_id = self.object.get_last_version_id()
            last_process = Process.objects.get(process_id=last_id)
            last_process_dict = last_process.__dict__
            related_processes = last_process.related_processes.all()[:]
            exclude = ['_state', 'process_id']
            for key, value in last_process_dict.items():
                if key not in exclude:
                    self.object.__dict__[key] = value

            # self.object.related_processes.add(*related_processes)
            # Remember this line too ^

            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def post(self, request, process_id):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect('my_app:show_process_page', form.cleaned_data['process_id'])
```

The first view is a simple FormView with ProcessForm. The second view is an UpdateView. On post I just add the field that is disabled on the form (and therefore is not passed ahead normally). On form_valid I just save the form on its model (with the just added field).

The third view is my current problem. Keep in mind that I can do 3 things with a Process: create a new one, edit it, or create a new version of an existing process. This third view intends to do the third one.
On get, I check if I'm trying to create a process that already exists. If it doesn't, I create the Process and copy all useful data on the base process to it, except the ManyToMany field (the second "remember this line"), because I couldn't figure out a way to do that without saving the Model first.
On post, I'm checking if the form is valid, and on form_valid, I'm saving the process.

## What works

I can create and edit processes just fine. The read-only fields when editing works perfectly. The model is saved as intended.
Also, I can create a new process using another existing process as a base (NewVersionProcessView) if the first "remember this line" is commented, that is, if all the fields are editable.

## What doesn't work

If the first "remember this line" is uncommented, that is, if some of the fields are read-only, my view crashes on post. Most specifically, on form_invalid. The only thing I can think of is that somehow there's not a Process object linked to my NewVersionProcessView. I can't understand why though, because I always assign something to `self.object` on get. I cannot get the object from the database on post because it is not saved yet. Also, I cannot understand why a field being enabled or disabled affects `self.object`. Remember, the only thing that changes is that `field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'true'` line.
Here is the log:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/new_version/999-11/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.4.4
Installed Applications:
['my_app.apps.MyAppConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\my_app\views.py" in post
  124.          return self.form_invalid(form)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_invalid
  61.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_context_data
  67.         return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_context_data
  93.         if self.object:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /my_app/new_version/999-11/
Exception Value: 'NewVersionProcessView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

I can provide the urls.py and the htmls if needed.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460708/checkoutview-object-has-no-attribute-object

Comment: My process_id is just something like this: "<int:real_id>-<int:version>".
When I do...
`self.object = Process(process_id=process_id)`
`last_id = self.object.get_last_version_id()`
... I'm creating a process with this new id, assigning to self.object, and getting the base process id (that is <int:version> minus one) just to copy data. I believe this is working as expected.

Comment: @RafaelC I cannot do `self.get_object()` because the object is not saved yet on the database. It just gives me a 404. I thought that if I assigned an object to self.object on get, it would still be acessible on post. I'm mistaken?